# Django EC2 mod_wsgi configuration with Apache not working

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I think my apache2 server is close to being set up but it's still returning a 500 error. Here is my `.wsgi` file:

```
import os, sys

#path to directory of the .wsgi file ('apache/')
wsgi_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

#path to project root directory (parent of 'apache/')
project_dir = os.path.dirname(wsgi_dir)

sys.path.append(project_dir)
project_settings = os.path.join(project_dir, 'settings')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ecomstore.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Here is my `virtualhost` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin admin@site.com
      ServerName www.site.com
      ServerAlias site.com

      Alias /static /home/ecomstore/static

      DocumentRoot /home/ecomstore
      WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ecomstore/apache/ecomstore.wsgi

      ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

      LogLevel warn

      CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

 </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my server restart:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Sun Apr 08 02:47:31 2012] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
 ... waiting ..........[Sun Apr 08 02:47:42 2012] [warn] module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
   ...done.
```

However, even though I get no errors with mod-wsgi configuration on the restart, I still get the 500 Internal Server error mentioned before. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to look at the Apache error logs from when you made the request and not when you did the restart.

One source of problems is that sys.path does not include the parent directory of the project directory which would be necessary because of what you set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to. Go read about this requirement in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

and fix it.

Beyond that, you need to work out whether it is an Apache 500 page or a Django one. If it is a Django one, then turn on DEBUG in Django settings file and restart Apache so you get a full error shown in browser. Turn off DEBUG when you have resolved.

Comment: Yeah I checked teh logs and found this: `ImportError: Could not import settings 'ecomstore.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named ecomstore.settings
`

Comment: Fixed the problem above by adding `sys.path.append('/home')`

Comment: BTW, ill advices to set DocumentRoot to what you have. If you stuff up Apache configuration later on, all your source code could be downloadable, including database passwords in Django settings file. Never set DocumentRoot to be a location which contains sensitive stuff you don't want users to be able to see.